# Split factor levels into new levels dependent upon position in a time series

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to work out how to split factor levels into new levels dependent upon their position in a time series.

Take some toy data:

```
Time <- c(1:18)
Factor <- as.factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3))
Value <- c(rnorm(18))
df <- data.frame(Time, Factor, Value)
str(df)
'data.frame':   18 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Time  : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Factor: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 1 ...
 $ Value : num  -0.728 -0.715 1.771 -0.54 -0.433 ...
```

With this data, the variable Factor is a factor with 3 levels. I want to split the levels depending upon its occurrence in the time series. So the first time a block of Factor 1 occurs I want to rename it 1.1,1.1,1.1 the second time it occurs I want to rename it 1.2, 1.2, 1.2 etc.

Can anyone suggest a way of doing this?
May real data has a variable `MIU_VALVE` which is a factor with 13 levels that I wont to apply any suggestions to. Here is the structure of my real data:

```
str(data1)
'data.frame':   85874 obs. of  19 variables:
 $ Time       : POSIXct, format: "2015-06-08 09:55:48" "2015-06-08 09:55:48"     "2015-06-08 09:55:49" "2015-06-08 09:55:50" ...
 $ [N2O]_ppm  : num  0.333 0.333 0.334 0.333 0.333 ...
 $ d15NA      : num  -17.9 -41.1 -49 -32.4 -29.2 ...
 $ d15NB      : num  -28.4 -56.7 -21.2 -61.3 -59.7 ...
 $ d18O       : num  -337 -291 -287 -284 -304 ...
 $ d15N       : num  -23.2 -48.9 -35.1 -46.8 -44.4 ...
 $ SP         : num  10.5 15.6 -27.8 28.9 30.5 ...
 $ [NNO]_ppm  : num  0.328 0.328 0.328 0.328 0.328 ...
 $ [NN15O]_ppm: num  0.00238 0.00233 0.00231 0.00235 0.00236 ...
 $ [N15NO]_ppm: num  0.00236 0.00229 0.00238 0.00228 0.00228 ...
 $ [NNO18]_ppm: num  0.000435 0.000466 0.000469 0.000471 0.000457 ...
 $ [H2O]_ppm  : num  33880 33817 34059 33714 33399 ...
 $ GasP_torr  : num  45.4 45.4 45.4 45.4 45.4 ...
 $ GasT_C     : num  41.3 41.3 41.3 41.3 41.3 ...
 $ AmbT_C     : num  42.2 42.2 42.2 42.2 42.2 ...
 $ LTC0_v     : num  0.0434 0.0434 0.0434 0.0434 0.0434 ...
 $ AIN6       : num  1.16 1.16 1.16 1.16 1.16 ...
 $ DetOff     : num  1.13 1.13 1.13 1.13 1.13 ...
 $ MIU_VALVE  : Factor w/ 13 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), create a run-length id variable ('gr') , grouped by 'Factor', we `match` the 'gr' with `unique` elements of 'gr' and `paste` the 'Factor' with that index to create the new variable 'Factor1'.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
setDT(df)[, gr := rleid(Factor)
   ][, Factor1 :=paste(Factor, match(gr, unique(gr)),sep='.') , by = Factor
     ][, gr := NULL]

df
#    Time Factor       Value Factor1
# 1:    1      1 -0.85048947     1.1
# 2:    2      1 -0.01022297     1.1
# 3:    3      1  1.03636468     1.1
# 4:    4      2  0.73873050     2.1
# 5:    5      2  0.94553427     2.1
# 6:    6      2  1.41944508     2.1
# 7:    7      3 -0.43160988     3.1
# 8:    8      3 -0.11538509     3.1
# 9:    9      3 -0.66212385     3.1
#10:   10      1 -0.97640087     1.2
#11:   11      1 -2.13485778     1.2
#12:   12      1 -0.18982403     1.2
#13:   13      2  0.47546599     2.2
#14:   14      2  0.79378768     2.2
#15:   15      2  1.04461781     2.2
#16:   16      3  0.29617799     3.2
#17:   17      3  0.17126235     3.2
#18:   18      3  0.36256006     3.2
```

---

Or a `base R` option would be using `rle` to get the run-length encoding, change the 'values' by the sequence after grouping by 'values', and `paste` with the 'Factor' column.

```
df$Factor1 <- paste(df$Factor, 
        inverse.rle(within.list(rle(as.character(df$Factor)), 
               values <-ave(lengths, values, FUN=seq_along))), 
                   sep='.')
df$Factor1
#[1] "1.1" "1.1" "1.1" "2.1" "2.1" "2.1" "3.1" "3.1" "3.1" "1.2" "1.2" "1.2" "2.2" "2.2" "2.2" "3.2" "3.2" "3.2"
```